# Delete a Camera driver to multiple machines that have different OEM.inf

Tags: camera, driver

Latest Sonix Camera driver seems to have upset teams calls on multiple devices (same model), so I need to delete that driver and run a stable version.

I have been trying to use pnputil, and although I have the GUid / instance name of the cameras (all the same), the oem.inf are different.

Is there a way to delete the drivers from all these devices despite their oem.inf files being different?